# Angular2 unit test environment setup? How to do trigger mouse event?

Tags: jasmine, protractor, angular

Is it better to test angular2 code use Jasmine core or use protractor?

It seems so hard to test with mouse event in Jasmine, can anyone know how to do with it? Can we do as simple as it likes in protractor: element1.click().

Answer (score 2):

This question is vague. Jasmine is a framework and can be used to execute tests against any stack, E2E, integration, unit. Protractor is an E2E testing framework that understands Angular directives and customizes WDJS control flow etc. They are not the same thing.

If you want to test the side effects of a click, unit test the event. The DOM reacts to the view model, so just test the state of the view model. This will be much faster.Protractor is useful when its unit tests wont fit, so you have to write a functional test. Always start with unit, and move out if it can't be tested that way

[See (outdated) docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/testing/)

Comment: So it's sounds like for unit test, it's better to use jasmine. Do you know if any reference about doing unit test on angular2 with jasmine? The official doc is not very detailed, it even didn't mention about how to do some mouse event.

Comment: Angular components force you to write encapsulated, easy to unit test code. They are awesome, see here:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/testing/first-app-tests.html

Remember an event is just a method. You can mock $event if you need access to the event info.